# R: define row that does not match previous row with group_by

Tags: dplyr

I have dataframe like this

| game | possession |
| --- | --- |
| A - B | A |
| A - B | A |
| A - B | A |
| A - B | B |
| A - B | A |
| C - D | D |
| C - D | D |
| C - D | C |
| C - D | C |
| C - D | D |

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  game = c("A - B", "A - B", "A - B", "A - B", "A - B", "C - D", "C - D", "C - D", "C - D", "C - D"),
  possession = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "D", "D", "C", "C", "D")
)
```

So I would like to add third column to define cases when Possession value changes.

I've tried something like this

```
df %>% 
group_by(game) %>% 
mutate(transit = ifelse(df$possession != dplyr::lag(df$possession), "yes", "no"))
```

But it does not work with group_by.

So my desired output is

| game | possession | transit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A - B | A | NA |
| A - B | A | no |
| A - B | A | no |
| A - B | B | yes |
| A - B | A | yes |
| C - D | D | NA |
| C - D | D | no |
| C - D | C | yes |
| C - D | C | no |
| C - D | D | yes |

Comment: Your second line needs to be `mutate(tmp = ifelse(possession != lag(possession), "yes", "no"))`. You've already piped "df" in so no need to redeclare it.

Answer (score 0):

LT's comment works, though if you would prefer a one line answer:

```
df <- mutate(df, tmp = possession != lag(possession), .by = game)
```